# The best way to "move" in Modern OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm deadling with Modern OpenGL (version 2.1+). It has more differents from classic versions. All is buffer, vertex buffer, element buffer, uniform buffer, .. and classic ways to do somethings is deprecated :-|...

**My question:** What is the best way to "move" (anyway, transformation in gereral) in modern opengl?

Currently, i do this way:

```
void render()
{
    glUseProgram(hProg);

    ...
    modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f); // like glLoadIdentity()
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uni_modelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_object_1);
    glVertexArrayPointer(...);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_object_1);
    glDrawElements(...);

    modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uni_modelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_object_2);
    glVertexArrayPointer(...);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_object_2);
    glDrawElements(...);
}
```

Comment: That looks correct to me. Is there some reason you're looking for a "better" solution? You could research using VAO to save on a few commands each frame, but that's up to you if your performance needs require it.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for quick reply, I just want a way which spend lowest resource (calculation, memory) for best performance and anyway, my way to do this is not more different from others :D. Thanks for your advise about VAO, i will learn in near future

Comment: How do you define "move"? And how do you define "best"?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sorry for my noob English :-(, "move" my means is the transformations like glTranslate, glRotate, glScale, .... and the "best" is some ways that consuming lowest resources like calculation and memory cost :)

Comment: The only thing that would arguably be "better" (in a sense of slightly faster) than what you already do would be to pass the position of the origin as a vertex attribute as it's done in pseudo-instancing. However, what you are doing (passing a MVP matrix as uniform) is the normal "correct" way, and it's probably good for 99.9% of all cases. You'll only really see a difference with several hundred thousand batches.

Comment: I am confused about this myself.Move/rotate/translation happens relatively infrequently (few times a second) as opposed to rendering itself which happens hundreds of times a second.Keeping this in mind,it appears it would be prudent to do all the math on client itself and send the final modelviewtransformation matrix as a uniform to the shader.But, matrix math happens much faster in a shader since its done on hardware (GPU) dedicated to crunching matrix mults.So then you'd rather send the three matrices as uniforms to the shader and do the mults there even if it be per frame.What's better?